# Better way fo filter boolean value from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What's the difference between these 2 methods?

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.approved
    self.where("approved = 1") 
  end
  def self.approved
    where approved: true 
  end
end
```

Comment: `1` is integer and `true` is boolean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So..some code again

```
1.9.3p374 :001 > 1 == true
 => false 
1.9.3p374 :002 > 0 == false
 => false
```

1 is not true, and 0 is not false. It means, first is used when type of `approved` column is integer, and second - boolean